How to trigger animation when visible in viewport
I have seen almost every solution but still I cannot make my text animate only when visible in viewport.
I tried to create and animate text using html widget in elementor because elementor default animations are not so good but animation starts when page is load even when user is not on that section making user unable to see animation. delay is also not suitable to fix so I want to fix it by animating when in viewport. so can someone kindly provide me with additional code to fix that. I am not coder so I will appreciate if someone can also explain along with solution.
following is the code I used
<h1 class="ml12">A new production</h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>




.ml12 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}

.ml12 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}



// Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml12');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: false})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml12 .letter',
    translateX: [40,0],
    translateZ: 0,
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 1200,
    delay: (el, i) => 500 + 30 * i
  })

